# Map items in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying  to map items in a list to the keys present in a dictionary. The item is mapped to the key of `dict2` if it is present in the value of `dict2`

```
list = ['abc','c-abc','ith','xyz']
dict2 = {'abc':['abc','ABC','c-abc'], 'xyz':['xyz']}


map=[]
for item in list:
    print(type(dict2.items()))
    for key,value in dict2.items():
        if item in value:
           map.append(key)
```

Output obtained:

```
['abc', 'abc', 'xyz']
```

Expected Output:

```
['abc', 'abc', 'ith', 'xyz']
```

`ith` doesn't occur in any of the values of  `dict2`. Therefore, it is not saved in `map`. But, I would like to know how it can be saved when `item` doesn't occur in any of the values of `dict2`.
I am not sure how to retain the item in `list` when a map is not found.

Any suggestions?

Comment: why is `abc` returned twice? why is `ith` expected?

Comment: why you expected `ith`? I didn't find it in `dict2 = {'abc':['abc','ABC','c-abc'], 'xyz':['xyz']}` values

Comment: Your algorithm is working correctly, could you please be clearer regarding what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The script runs the second loop for each ```list``` item and checks if that ```list``` item is contained within the value of the ```dict2```s items. If thats the case **key** of the ```dict2``` item that contains a value from ```list``` would be added to the map. Which goes like this **list_item -> dict2_item_key** ```abc -> abc | c-abc -> abc | ith -> None | xyz-> xyz```. **ith** is not contained within ```dict2```s items so it is not added.

Comment: @BerkayÖz Yes, I have updated my post. I'd like to store the `item` , if it doesn't occur in any of the values of `dict2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do is check if the list item is present in the dictionary's value. If it is, append the key to the 'map' list, and if it isn't keep the value.

Please be clearer explaining what you want.

```
list = ['abc','c-abc','ith','xyz']
dict2 = {'abc':['abc','ABC','c-abc'], 'xyz':['xyz']}


map=[]
for item in list:
    found = false
    for key,value in dict2.items():
        if item in value:
            map.append(key)
            found = true
    if not found:
        map.append(item)
```